# Celery - Django Schedule task from inside a scheduled task

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have a Task (let's call it MainTask) that is scheduled using `apply_async` method, this task has some validations that can trigger another task (SecondaryTask) to be scheduled with an `eta`.

Every time the MainTask tries to schedule the SecondaryTask using `apply_async` method, the SecondaryTask runs inmediatly, overriding the `eta` parameter.

**How can I schedule a different task from a "Main Task" and to be executed later, using `eta`?**

Here is an example of the code:

views.py

```
def function():
    main_task.apply_async(eta=some_day)
```

tasks.py

```
@app.task(bind=True, name="main_task", autoretry_for=(Exception,), default_retry_delay=10, max_retries=3, queue='mail')
def main_task(self):
    ...
    if something:
        ...
        another_task.apply_async(eta=tomorrow)

@app.task(bind=True, name="another_task", autoretry_for=(Exception,), default_retry_delay=10, max_retries=3, queue='mail')
    def another_task(self):
        do_something()
```

I'm using Celery 4.4.6 btw

Answer (score 0):

What celery version are you using?

I'm with 4.4.7 and using `countdown` which is kind of the [same](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown) (maybe there's a bug with `eta`?):

> countdown is a shortcut to set ETA by seconds into the future.

assuming that you are doing something similar to this:

```
tomorrow = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=1)
```

you can always get the seconds and use with `countdown`:

```
seconds = timedelta(days=1).total_seconds()
another_task.apply_async(countdown=seconds)
```

**EDIT**:

can you try to `apply_async` on `signature` to see if that makes a difference?

```
another_task.si().apply_async(eta=tomorrow)
```

Comment: Im using Celery 4.4.6, the thing is that ¨apply_async¨ is not scheduling a new task, it executes the task inmediatly like ¨apply¨ does. there is no change using eta or countdown

Comment: Did u try delay() instead?

Comment: + see my EDIT above